# How can I use queue_free() with Area2D

Tags: godot

When an Object enters Area2D I expect an object entering to be removed but nothing happens

I have tried queue_free(area) and Area2d.queue_free()

```
func _on_Area2D_area_entered(area):
    queue_free()
    area.queue_free
```

Like said above nothing happens when an object enters Area2d

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193176/discussion-on-question-by-john-tobey-how-can-i-use-queue-free-with-area2d).

Comment: I wrote this in the chat too - just in case you missed it. 
I believe you can attach the script to a `KinematicBody` in a different scene... I've tested this too. I created a separate scene with only the `KinematicBody`. I then linked the scene to the (main) scene containing the `Area2d` (by default it appears as `Node2D` in the node hierarchy). I then attached a blank script to the `Node2D` (necessary for signal to be attached), then attached a signal from `Area2D` to the `Node2D` (`_on_body_entered`) and set it to `queue_free()` on this event. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have made a simple project to test the collision and `queue_free()` process with regards to an interaction between `KinematicBody` and `Area2D`. Basically, the `Area2D` is the object that detects and signals a collision (`KinematicBody` can cause a collision, but not detect it). Therefore it is up to `Area2D` to detect when a BODY has entered (or in this case, when it enters a body), and then it can signal the collision, which then calls the `_on_Area2D_body_entered` function in the other object, and then executes `queue_free()` as instructed.

My node setup is as follows:

```
Node2D
|_Area2D - (SIGNAL ATTACHED - "_on_body_entered()" - CONNECTED TO KINEMATIC BODY)
|   |_Sprite
|   |_CollisionShape2D
|
|_KinematicBody2D
    |_Sprite
    |_CollisionShape2D
```

For my trial, the `Area2D` object is placed on same horizontal axis, and to the left of the `KinematicBody`

SCRIPT ATTACHED TO AREA2D:

```
extends Area2D

func _ready():
    pass 

func _process(delta):
    self.position.x += 1  #So it moves into and collides with other object.
```

SCRIPT ATTACHED TO KINEMATICBODY:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

func _ready():
    pass 

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body): # This is called when Area2D detects a collision
    queue_free()
    print("HIT!!!!!") #To doubly confirm the collision is recognized
```

Unfortunately, it kind of has to be this way. Since `Area2D` is the only object in this scenario which is capable of detecting and signalling the collision, it cannot be ordered to `queue_free()` itself, as Godot throws an error when attempting to do so.

Alternatively, however, if you wanted it the other way around - for the `KinematicBody` to move towards the `Area2D` object, and delete itself upon impact. simply move the whole delta process from the `Area2D` script and place it in the `KinematicBody` script above the `_on_Area2D_body_entered(body)` and change the `self.position.x` to `-= 1`. Leave the signal on the `Area2D`.

Comment: can you send me a copy of the project? I dont know how to link nodes from outside the scene

Comment: The link (instance) button is at the top of your node viewer panel between the plus (add child node) sign and the "filter nodes" search box. It looks like a little chain link.

Comment: I can send you the test project... I just don't know how. E-mail maybe?

Comment: how would i give you my email privately? also sorry for ghosting you

Comment: I uploaded it to a drive file - link is here -- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GOCFbJvq6W4Oq3L470FMm-EWV-U4GUAL. Sorry, it's been a while since we talked before, so I don't remember the details of the project (or if I modified my test since), so if it's not what you want, let me know, and i'll re-work it. I've done a lot of work with signals since we last spoke, so one way or another, we'll get this solved.

Comment: sorry for not responding ill remember to take a look at it